# Looping through $json variable and grabbing each id to add to an array

Tags: arrays, json, powershell-2.0

Given that I am processing the following `$json` variable, how would I grab each server id (i.e. `215d1109-216d-48c3-af8e-998bb9bc3ca0` and `440cf918-3ee0-4143-b289-f63e1d2000e6` in this case) and put it into an array?

Right now `$obj.servers.id` returns nothing (as expected), but `$obj.servers.id[0]` returns an error message.

```
clear
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions") | out-null
$json = '
{
    "servers": [
        {
            "admin_password": "qpYU66rKxmnK",
            "id": "215d1109-216d-48c3-af8e-998bb9bc3ca0",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/v3/servers/<id>",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/servers/<id>",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "admin_password": "wfksH3GTTseP",
            "id": "440cf918-3ee0-4143-b289-f63e1d2000e6",
            "links": [
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/v3/servers/<id>",
                    "rel": "self"
                },
                {
                    "href": "http://openstack.example.com/servers/<id>",
                    "rel": "bookmark"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
'
$ser = New-Object System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$obj = $ser.DeserializeObject($json)
$obj.servers.id;
```

Please note that I am using Powershell 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the structure of your data. `$obj.servers` is an array with two fields, each of which contains a dictionary, not an object containing an array `id`. You need to make the index access like this:

```
$obj.servers[0].id
```

`$obj.servers.id[0]` will certainly throw an error, because the array object `$obj.servers` doesn't have a property `id`, so in PowerShell v2 `$obj.servers.id` returns `$null`, and index access on a null array fails (as you'd expect).

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> [void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Web.Extensions')
$json = @'
...
'@
PS C:\> $ser = New-Object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
PS C:\> $obj = $ser.DeserializeObject($json)
PS C:\> $obj.servers.GetType().FullName
System.Object[]
PS C:\> $obj.servers.id -eq $null
True
PS C:\> $obj.servers[0].GetType().Name
Dictionary`2
PS C:\> $obj.servers[0] | Format-Table -AutoSize

Key            Value
---            -----
admin_password qpYU66rKxmnK
id             215d1109-216d-48c3-af8e-998bb9bc3ca0
links          {System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Str...

PS C:\> $obj.servers[0].id
215d1109-216d-48c3-af8e-998bb9bc3ca0
```

To extract all IDs simply pipe the array into a `ForEach-Object` loop where you echo the `id` property:

```
PS C:\> $ids = $obj.servers | % { $_.id }
PS C:\> $ids
215d1109-216d-48c3-af8e-998bb9bc3ca0
440cf918-3ee0-4143-b289-f63e1d2000e6
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a simple mistake. I also realised `$obj.server.id` should be `$obj.servers.id`. But I am not sure how I would loop through and grab each id value, then add it to an array?